# how to add View controller to every item on a menu?

Tags: drop-down-menu, uiviewcontroller

i'm sure it's pretty easy , but i'm spending hours to get it right . 
I download this simple menu from github :
https://github.com/Antondomashnev/ADDropDownMenuView

the view controller looks like this :

```
- (void)addDropDownMenu{

ADDropDownMenuView *dropDownMenuView = [[ADDropDownMenuView alloc] initAtOrigin:CGPointMake(0, 20)
                                                        withItemsViews:@[[self dropDownItemWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Item 1", @"")],
                                                                         [self dropDownItemWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Item 2", @"")],
                                                                         [self dropDownItemWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Item 3", @"")]]];
dropDownMenuView.delegate = self;
dropDownMenuView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview: dropDownMenuView];}
```

i'm adding 2 more view controllers to the storyboard. 
how can I connect them with Item 2 and Item 3 ? ( so I will see a different View every time i'll click different item ) .
any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed demo code to show you solution.
In ViewController.m file add private category with two properties

```
@interface ViewController ()<ADDropDownMenuDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *viewControllers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADDropDownMenuView *dropDownMenuView;

@end
```

Then you need to create set viewControllers array. For example i want to create two instances of ViewController2 class (clean UIViewController template) in `viewDidLoad`

```
ViewController2 *vc1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2Blue"];
[self addChildViewController:vc1];
ViewController2 *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2Yellow"];
[self addChildViewController:vc2];
self.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2];
```

You have to add these view controllers as a child view controller to `self`. Don't forget about setting storyboardID for your view controllers in storyboard. In this case first view controller has ViewController2Blue storyboardID and second has ViewController2Yellow.

And the last thing to do is implementing `ADDropDownMenuDelegate` method

```
- (void)ADDropDownMenu:(ADDropDownMenuView *)view didSelectItem:(ADDropDownMenuItemView *)item
{
    NSLog(@"%@ selected", item.titleLabel.text);
    for(UIViewController *viewController in self.viewControllers){
        [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if([item.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Item 1", @"")]){
        [self.view insertSubview:((ViewController2 *)self.viewControllers[0]).view belowSubview:self.dropDownMenuView];
    }
    else{
        [self.view insertSubview:((ViewController2 *)self.viewControllers[1]).view belowSubview:self.dropDownMenuView];
    }
}
```

In this method you remove all UIViewController's views from superview. And then according ADDropDownMenuItemView titleLabel text you add viewController's view to self view.